# No Column ({nullable:true, default: 0}) added in production mode

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, digital-ocean

I have a NestJS backend, with postgresql db deploy on digitalocean, I have updated entities, added several columns with nullable and default values, builded several times but tables are not updated.. Can anybody help? :( **shps_id** and **verified** are newly added. It works in development mode .. dropping little code snippet:

````
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ name: 'first_name' })
  first_name: string;

  @Column({ name: 'last_name' })
  last_name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  salt: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({default: 0})
  verified: number

  @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
  shps_id: 'string'

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  role: string;

} ```
````

Comment: This looks like ```TypeORM```. Perhaps the ```synchronize``` option of ```TypeORM``` is set to ```false``` in production? At least, this is what it should be. If so, you need to use migrations to update the data structures in the production environment. See here for more info: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md

Comment: Would need to know if you're using `synchronize` or `migrations` and the relevant parts of your `ormconfig.json` or `TypeOrmModule.forRoot/Async()` configuration.

Comment: thank you guys, it was because of synchronize ... i am going to study migrations )) @Islingre thanks